# Can I call prepare() separately on multiple models or should it be a single call when using accelerator with pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm training two deep learning models in tandem, say `model1` and `model2` using pytorch. I'm using `accelerator` to handle distributed training. When calling the `prepare()` function, can I call it separately as in the below code?

```
model1, dataloader, optimizer = accelerator.prepare(model1, dataloader, optimizer)
if some_condition:
    model2 = acceletator.prepare(model2)
```

Or do I have to call `prepare()` only once, as in the below code?

```
if not some_condition:
    model1, dataloader, optimizer = accelerator.prepare(model1, dataloader, optimizer)
else:
    model1, model2, dataloader, optimizer = acceletator.prepare(model1, model2, dataloader, optimizer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering [`Accelerate.prepare`](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/v0.27.2/en/package_reference/accelerator#accelerate.Accelerator.prepare) [iterates over each passed object individually](https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate/blob/v0.27.2/src/accelerate/accelerator.py#L1171), calling it twice will have the same effect. The expected list of argument should contain [`data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html), [`optim.Optimizer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer), or [`optim.lr_scheduler.LRScheduler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate), its purpose is to transfer to the desired device and cast to the desired data type.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the code link you shared. I found it hard to follow because of multiple nested function calls. Can you please confirm whether the operations applied on the arguments are independent of each other? In other words, is what I've done in my first chunk acceptable?